# Creating HTML page from Perl incl. Javascript: Refresh of Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, perl, dygraphs

I am currently coding my intranet site, running on a Synology NAS. Since the intranet page (via Javascript) cannot access any folder on the NAS outside it's "www" folder, I had to this on the server side with a Perl script, since the data which should be displayed lies outside the "www" folder on the NAS.

The perl script now writes the entire html page, including Javascript code which is needed to plot a chart via dygraphs. The most important thing the perl script does is process a .csv file and write

```
var $chartdata = [["2014/07/06 12:05", 15], ["2014/07/06 12:06"], 15.5, ...];
```

which is the series variable as the dygraphs library (dygraphs.com) needs it to display the chart. Therefore I am dynamically writing a javascript line within the "script" tag. With the perl variables passed in the URL (script.pl?day=07&month=06&year=2014) this variable is written differently.

This all displays on an iPad and works fine.

I now have implemented the swipe function and would like to refresh the chart with data the day before or after the displayed date, depening on swiping left or right. The swipe function also works.

My problem is, how do I refresh/rewrite the javascript variable without needing to refresh the entire page? It works just executing the entire perl script with new data in URL variables, which in turn rewrites the entire html page. But I'd just like to refresh the chart, i.e. the data for the chart.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Many thanks and best regards,
dmy

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Probably the easiest way to do what you want is to set up an endpoint on your server that runs the perl script and spits out JSON that your graphing function can understand. When the page loads, make a request that gives you the default graph; when a user swipes, make a new request that gives you the graph appropriate for that, etc.

If you're using jquery, you can use [this function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I'll then try to remove the html-writing from the perl-script and will attempt to fetch the data in the way you said, although I am not quite sure how to this exactly.

Comment: I don't write perl so I'm not sure what this looks like in your language, but you basically want to build a string that looks like: "{'response': [['2014/07/06 12:05', 15], ['2014/07/06 12:06'], 15.5, ...]}" and let jquery unpack it into a javascript data structure. Also, please upvote and/or accept this answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: I can without a problem build that string in perl, I am just not sure how the jquery code (unpacking) has to look like. I would upvote you if I only could, but "You need 15 reputation" does not allow me (yet).